# jQuery radio button in a ui tab, just can't seem to post the value

Tags: jquery, ajax, radio-button

This has cause some frustration, 
Heres my jquery, the show_values function is to show what I'm trying to post 'parky=Y'. the nameloc an input field works fine, so i don't understand why the radio button has resisted a days+ worth of effort to send it to the db.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(function() {
$( "#radio" ).buttonset();
});
$('input').addClass("ui-corner-all");
$('.save').click(function() {
var namloc = $('#namloc').val();
var parky = $("input:radio[name='parky']").serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: "main2.php",
    type: "post",
    data: 'Name_Loc='+namloc+'&parky'+parky,
    success: function(data) {
    $('.rowy').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
    }
});

function showValues() {
var parky = $("input:radio[name='parky']").serialize();
$( "#results" ).text( parky );
}
$( "input:radio[name='park']" ).on( "click", showValues );
$( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
showValues();
});
});
```

heres the html of the radio button, it is not in a form because I've tried to serialise within a form but as soon as i press submit the tab snaps shut and reloads. making it not user friendly, so i removed the form tag and am trying without.

```
echo "<label>Parking </label>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4\">";
echo "<div id=\"radio\">";
?>
<label for="r1">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" class="single-radio" id="r1" name="parky" value="Y">
<label for="r2">No</label>
<input type="radio" class="single-radio" id="r2" name="parky" value="N">
<?php
echo "</div>"; // radio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a `=` after `&parky`:

```
data: 'Name_Loc='+namloc+'&parky'+parky,
```

Comment: 'i don't believe it' said in my best victor meldrew voice!
one day of my life wasted ugh wah